# How can I find my Windows Experience Index score?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1-preview

The Windows Experience Index is missing from the control panel in the 8.1 preview. I had some scores in Windows 8 that capped out at 7.9, I was wondering what the real scores were with the new kernel.

How can I run the tests again?

Comment: You do understand your score isn't going to change right?

Comment: @Ramhound I see. I misunderstood the ceiling in Windows 8. I thought the max for Windows 8 was 7.9 (that's what my hardware scored in it and for some reason it scored over 8 in Windows 8.1). I didn't realize the ceiling had been 9.9 all along. My score did go up for some reason though, and my disk score went down.

Comment: Your score would be connected to the lowest number, which means, your worst metric improved by at least 0.1.  It was likely firwmware that put it over the edge.

Answer (score 4):

From an elevated command prompt enter: `winsat formal`

When the tests are complete, look in **%systemroot%\performance\winsat\datastore** for an XML file whose name matches the time you ran the test.

In the XML file, look at the WinSPR node, which should look something like this:
[image]